# Porting boost::asio tcp examples to C++11

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, visual-studio-2012, boost-asio

I am using a simple tcp server from boost::asio, which can be found 
[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server).

It works fine (Boost 1.51, VC++ 2012).

But when I try to change the typedef of `connection_ptr` from

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<connection> connection_ptr;
```

to

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<connection> connection_ptr;
```

the server still works, but it crashes after a connection is complete. It happens in [connection manager](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/connection_manager.cpp) in the method `stop`.

It seems that removing a boost shared_ptr works, but you cant remove a std shared_ptr? why would that be the case?

Comment: Did you also inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` instead of the boost version in `connection`?

Comment: I don't know about this particular case, but generally C++11 support in VC11 is still quite limited, I've seen some bugs in it already and  also boost 1.51 is not properly configured for VC11 yet. So I'd generally hold off replacing boost constructs with C++11 ones just yet. In fact I've used std::tr1 with boost-provided fallback in our codebase and progressively switched to explicit boost due to compiler differences and the last changes where due to VC11.

Comment: I removed this inheritance and simply pass a new instance of shared_ptr each time

Comment: Seems that you are making several shared_ptr to manage lifetime of same object. Or what was the message in crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding your comment

> I removed this inheritance and simply pass a new instance of
>   shared_ptr each time

Don't do this, this defeats the purpose of a `std::shared_ptr`. You need to use `std::enable_shared_from_this` and `shared_from_this()` to increment the reference count, creating another instance of a `shared_ptr` with the same pointee will just cause problems, such as memory access violations.